# layoutSubviews in infinite loop on iOS 8 GM

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, infinite-loop, layoutsubviews

My app subclasses a `UITableViewCell` and implements `layoutSubviews` to modify the cell's `contentView`'s width, like so:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    // position subviews...
    CGRect frame = [[self contentView] frame];
    frame.size.width -= 20;
    [[self contentView] setFrame:frame]; 
}
```

When running this code with the iOS 8 simulator and Xcode 6 GM seed, **this triggers an infinite loop**.  However, when running on a real iPhone or iPad running iOS 8 GM seed, it does not loop,  as in previous versions of iOS.

I first thought the difference was a compiler optimization, but the simulator loops in both debug configuration and release configuration.

**Questions**

- Why the difference between the iOS 8 GM and the simulator?
- Is this a critical bug fix? I'm very reluctant to release an app that exhibits a potentially serious hanging bug, even if I can't reproduce it on device.
- What in your opinion is the best way to refactor this to eliminate the looping without causing regression on iOS 7 and 6?

Comment: This code looks bad, imagine something happening on screen that causes all views to re-layout their subviews: your content views can be easily srank to zero width. Not saying that this is what's happening on  simulator, but I believe if you have such good attitude in regards to resolving possible bugs you might as well fix this issue. I'm yet to download the GM seed, then I shall test your code to see if the issue is easy to be reproduced, meanwhile it might be a good idea for you to pick one of the cells and post the backtrace of recursive (not the first) method calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me on one of the previous iOS 8 betas. Occurred on both device and simulator. After some debugging I found out that `UITableViewCell` probably uses autolayout internally on iOS8. Moreover, any changes to `contentView.frame` triggered `layoutSubviews` (which might be a reason of your infinite loop as well).

As a workaround, I added a subview to the cell's `contentView` and modified its `frame` instead. Then I used this view like I would use the `contentView` (as a superview of all the custom cell elements).

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on how to do this? I am having the same problem. I want to make sure detailView is adjusted to the correct width in landscape mode. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what is your exact problem. I created a gist showing the idea in code: https://gist.github.com/mciuba/5b9bb9842eb141bea01e. If this doesn't help, maybe ask a new question and provide more details there.

Comment: You are awesome, this would have taken me literally days. I was manually  calculating the height of the cell and changing the contentView frame in layoutSubviews. Turning  off autolayout on nib file fixed the issue.